# understanding ridge regression

Tags: r, regression

I started learning ridge regression in R. I applied the linear ridge regression and got the following results. How do I interpret the results?

```
> gridge<-lm.ridge(divorce ~., data=divusa, lambda=seq(0,35,0.02))
> select(gridge)
modified HKB estimator is 0.07693804 
modified L-W estimator is 0.3088377 
smallest value of GCV  at 0.02 
> which.min(gridge$GCV)
 0.02 
    2 

> round(coef(gridge)[2,-1],3)
      year     unemployed     femlab   marriage      birth 
    -0.195        -0.053             0.790      0.148     -0.118 
  military 
    -0.042 

> round(coef(g)[-1],3)
      year      unemployed     femlab   marriage      birth 
    -0.203         -0.049              0.808      0.150     -0.117 
  military 
    -0.043
```

Questions:

1. How do I interpret the results?
2. Do I have to do anything else for interpretation?

Comment: This is better asked on [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: question is listed here on CrossValidated:
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/40588/how-do-you-interpret-the-results-from-ridge-regression

Answer (score -3):

```
ridge <- lm.ridge (LKyes~ ., lambda = "automatic", data=ml)


Error in svd(X) : infinite or missing values in 'x'
```